# what is the best solution to high electrical bill

Tags: power-consumption

My friends and colleagues are always complaining to me now, the more wages grow, the higher prices rise, particularly electricity high unacceptably, when sitting at home, nothing to do, just leave the lights on for a month to ten at night, not to mention the use of household appliances,

Comment: Sorry, but this site only handles questions which can be specifically answered.

Comment: @Chris -- I believe this is so. See my answer ;-)

Comment: Install solar panels (with all the required equipment).  Make your own electricity.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an engineering question.

Answer (score 6):

Turn things off.............................